# How to block YouTube in general on my daughter's phone while allowing her to follow her favourite YouTubers?

Tags: youtube

While YouTube Kids app is allowed on my daughter's Android phone, YouTube app is blocked. Recently I realized she still accesses youtube.com through her web browser so she can follow her favourite gaming YouTubers (on YouTube Kids app she can't follow their channels, she can only find their videos one by one through a general search, which is extremely annoying and unsatisfying).

Is there a way to either follow a channel in YouTube kids or to allow the following of a channel in YouTube app or in web youtube.com while blocking YouTube in general?